# asp.net mvc create dynamic tabs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul id="editorRows">
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<WebSiteLanguage>)ViewBag.WebSiteLanguages)
        {
            @*<li><a href=@Url.Action("PageLanguageWiseContent", "Page", new { LangId = item.LangId })><span>@item.Language.LangName</span></a></li>*@
              <li><a href="#@item.LangName"><span>@item.LangName</span></a></li>
        }
    </ul>
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<WebSiteLanguage>)ViewBag.WebSiteLanguages)
        {
            <div id="@item.LangName">
            @{
                Html.RenderAction("PageLanguageWiseContent",new { LangId = item.LangId });
             }

            </div>
        }
</div>
```

how can i create tabs in one loop? Any other approach which will allow me to use only one loop?

Comment: Why do you only want to do a single loop? This code works right?

Comment: yes The code works right

Comment: Did you tried putting the div inside the li , i mean along with 1st loop

Comment: You might need to bind some `if` statements inside `for` loop checking for `item` index and then wrap `<ul>` for 1st index and `</ul>` for last index and remaining `<li>` things in between and the `div` after `if-else` which puts all under `for loop`

Comment: You still didn't answer my initial question, why do you want it in a single loop? If it's not broken, then there is no need to fix it...

Comment: @DavidG i am hoping that maybe there is some other solution other then these two loops that I am not aware off. two same loops up and down doesn't seem nicer to me. i have gone through some sites highlighting some scenarios even advance scenarios  but none highlighted the thing i am looking for.

Comment: so maybe this is the way to do it as you pointed out

Comment: You can't because you have 2 different parent elements and you're creating different lists of elements within them. If you wanted to shift load from server to client, then you'd send down a single view model and to the binding via knockout.js or whatever. Tho that would actually then be 3 loops ; 1 on server 2 on client; but it would likely scale "better"? You could also look at the OutputCacheAttribute and then maybe you wouldn't  have any loops at all (after the first request)